# Is method call from an SDK-DLL responsive c#

Tags: c#, api, dll, sdk, ping

I am writing a c# application that uses SDK/dlls of a CAD software.
I noticed a situation when the user run my application while his/her CAD software is busy doing something (saving a large file--hence is not responsive), my app hangs because it calls that CAD software to get current file name.

Is there a way to sort of ping that CAD software?

A scenario is:

- get current file name in cad software.
- if cad software has not returned a value back for like.. x milliseconds, then stop the my application call.

I am new to c# so there might solutions for this, but I am not sure how to ask the right question.

Comment: You’ll likely need to call the CAD system on a background thread in order to avoid blocking your UI thread. It’s difficult to advise you further without any code from you.

Comment: thanks. I'll make a block of code and post back.

Comment: Are you using COM?

Comment: yes i am. this worked for me. 

 
`public static bool Ping()
{
           var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("3DEXPERIENCE");
            return proc[0].Responding;
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work for me

```
public static bool Ping()
{
           var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("3DEXPERIENCE");
            return proc[0].Responding;
 }
```